# Form1 does not start

Tags: c#, forms, server, message

So I'm developing an Server-Client app, and yesterday I solved a problem with the messages.

([Server side not reading message correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281390/server-side-not-reading-message-correctly?noredirect=1#comment48662674_30281390))

Today, I'm facing a new problem.
My objective is to click in a website button by his ID, using messages that come from the Client. So I created a mini WebBrowser that displays the Website I want to use. The problem is that if I start the server with the mini WebBrowser, the browser itself wont show up, but if I remove

```
serverfunction();
```

it will show up but the server wont be open, i will gladly accept any help. TIA

Source code C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serverfunction();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void serverfunction()
        {
            int port = 80;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.68");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            server.Start();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
            string data;

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Global.message = StripExtended(data);
                Console.WriteLine(Global.message);
            }
        }

        static string StripExtended(string arg)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(arg.Length); //Max length
            foreach (char ch in arg)
            {
                UInt16 num = Convert.ToUInt16(ch);//In .NET, chars are UTF-16
                //The basic characters have the same code points as ASCII, and the extended characters are bigger
                if ((num >= 32u) && (num <= 126u)) buffer.Append(ch);
            }
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Global
    {
        public static string message = "";
    } 
}
```

Comment: serverfunction() enters an infinite loop. Calling it anywhere in your winform application will stop your application forever. I think you need a separate thread to run that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `ServerFunction` call creates an infinite loop

```
while (true)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can solve that easily by pushing it to a background thread.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(() => serverfunction());
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void serverfunction()
        {
            int port = 80;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.68");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            server.Start();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
            string data;

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Global.message = StripExtended(data);
                Console.WriteLine(Global.message);
            }
        }

        static string StripExtended(string arg)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(arg.Length); //Max length
            foreach (char ch in arg)
            {
                UInt16 num = Convert.ToUInt16(ch);//In .NET, chars are UTF-16
                //The basic characters have the same code points as ASCII, and the extended characters are bigger
                if ((num >= 32u) && (num <= 126u)) buffer.Append(ch);
            }
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Global
    {
        public static string message = "";
    }
}
```

You'll want to make sure you marshall any UI interaction back to the UI thread.

However I don't believe that to be the best solution. You should avoid a `while` loop all together. Instead, as described by [my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30294179/1815321), you should use the `Begin/EndInvoke` pattern with the `Socket` class. Also, I typically frown on "global" variables like what you have.

You could create a client connection like the following:

#### ServerMessageArgs

We need an `EventArgs` class that will  be used to push messages received to the Form.

```
public class ServerMessageArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ServerMessageArgs(string message)
    {
        this.ServerMessage = message;
    }

    public string ServerMessage { get; private set; }
}
```

#### ClientConnection

This class handles connecting to a server, and processing any message received. When data is received, it raises the event handler and passes it along to the Form.

```
public class ClientConnection : IDisposable
{

    private const int _bufferSize = 1024;
    private Socket socket = null;

    public event EventHandler Connected;
    public event EventHandler<ServerMessageArgs> ServerMessageArrived;

    public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }

    public void ConnectToServerAsync(string url, int port)
    {
        var endPoint = this.GetIPEndPointFromHostName(url, port, false);
        this.socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        this.socket.BeginConnect(endPoint, new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectedCallback), this.socket);

        this.IsConnected = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.socket.Connected)
        {
            this.socket.Disconnect(false);
        }

        this.socket.Dispose();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        // Strip the ending carriage return and linefeed characters and re-add them
        // We do this in the event that only one out of the two were provided, or they 
        // came in out of order.
        message = $"{message.TrimEnd('\r', '\n')}\r\n";

        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        this.socket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), this.socket);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = this.socket.EndSend(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ConnectedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        this.socket.EndConnect(result);
        var handler = this.Connected;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new EventArgs());

        this.ReceiveData();
    }

    private void ReceiveData()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];

        this.socket.BeginReceive(
            buffer,
            0,
            _bufferSize,
            0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
            buffer);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (!this.IsConnected)
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
        int bytesRead = this.socket.EndReceive(result);
        var contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string content = string.Empty;

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            contentBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            foreach (string message in contentBuilder.ToString().Split('\n'))
            {
                this.OnServerMessageArrived(message);
            }

            //  Get the rest of the data.
            this.socket.BeginReceive(
                (buffer = new byte[_bufferSize]),
                0,
                _bufferSize,
                0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
                buffer);
        }
    }

    private void OnServerMessageArrived(string content)
    {
        var handler = this.ServerMessageArrived;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new ServerMessageArgs(content));
    }

    private IPEndPoint GetIPEndPointFromHostName(string hostName, int port, bool throwIfMoreThanOneIP)
    {
        var addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
        if (addresses.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Unable to retrieve address from specified host name.",
                "hostName"
            );
        }
        else if (throwIfMoreThanOneIP && addresses.Length > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "There is more that one IP address to the specified host.",
                "hostName"
            );
        }
        return new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], port); // Port gets validated here.
    }
}
```

#### Form1

Now the Form just looks like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ClientConnection client;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new ClientConnection();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.ServerMessageArrived += (s, message) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            client.SendMessage($"{message} received by server.");
        };

        client.Connected += (s, args) => Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
        client.ConnectToServerAsync("192.168.1.68", 80);
    }
}
```

I was not able to test the above, due to not knowing what data is expected back, but this code was lifted from an IRC app that I wrote, using the async pattern and pruning the app of while loops.

## Edit

After posting the client connection code above, I realized that your question was regarding the server hanging. I would still remove the while loop. You can use the async pattern I mentioned in the link above, which was for server-side. In order to ensure the answer is part of this post, I will share the code here as well.

#### Server Status

We need to have a way of checking what the current server status is. This can be as simple as a small `enum`.

```
public enum ServerStatus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The server has stopped.
    /// </summary>
    Stopped,

    /// <summary>
    /// Server is in the process of starting.
    /// </summary>
    Starting,

    /// <summary>
    /// Server is up and running.
    /// </summary>
    Running
}
```

#### ConnectedArgs

Next, the Server class needs to raise some events so that the `Form` code-behind can be told when a client connects, and when the client has sent the server a message. We will provide a class called `ConnectedArgs` as our event handler argument. This class will hold a reference to our actual client, using the wrapper class we will create next.

```
public class ConnectedArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ConnectedArgs(ConnectionState state)
    {
        this.ConnectedClient = state;
    }

    public ConnectionState ConnectedClient { get; private set; }
}
```

#### ConnectionState

This class is responsible for holding the `Socket` associated with the connected client, and handle receiving the clients message data asynchronously. This uses the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` async pattern [included with the Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30294179/1815321).

This class will have an event that will be used to notify the `Form` that a new message was received. Note that this was pulled from one of my existing projects, so the data parsing basically checks the buffer and if the buffer does not include a \r\n, it is considered incomplete. It caches it and waits for the next chunk of data from the client to process and try and complete. You will want to replace the `ProcessReceivedData` method with your custom method that handles processing the received data. When you are done, just push the results in to the `OnDataReceived` method so your `Form` can be given it.

```
public sealed class ConnectionState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The size of the buffer that will hold data sent from the client
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int bufferSize;

    /// <summary>
    /// A temporary collection of incomplete messages sent from the client. These must be put together and processed.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<string> currentData = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// What the last chunk of data sent from the client contained.
    /// </summary>
    private string lastChunk = string.Empty;

    public ConnectionState(Socket currentSocket, int bufferSize)
    {
        this.CurrentSocket = currentSocket;
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
        this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is raised when the server has received new, valid, data from the client.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<string> DataReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Socket for the player associated with this state.
    /// </summary>
    public Socket CurrentSocket { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the data currently in the network buffer
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets if the current network connection is in a valid state.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsConnectionValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CurrentSocket != null && this.CurrentSocket.Connected;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts listening for network communication sent from the client to the server
    /// </summary>
    public void StartListeningForData()
    {
        this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        this.CurrentSocket.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Receives the input data from the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The result.</param>
    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // If we are no longer in a valid state, dispose of the connection.
        if (!this.IsConnectionValid)
        {
            this.CurrentSocket?.Dispose();
            return;
        }

        int bytesRead = this.CurrentSocket.EndReceive(result);
        if (bytesRead == 0 || !this.Buffer.Any())
        {
            this.StartListeningForData();
            return;
        }

        ProcessReceivedData(bytesRead);
        this.StartListeningForData();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process the data we received from the client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytesRead"></param>
    private void ProcessReceivedData(int bytesRead)
    {
        // Encode our input string sent from the client
        this.lastChunk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        // If the previous chunk did not have a new line feed, then we add this message to the collection of currentData.
        // This lets us build a full message before processing it.
        if (!lastChunk.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            // Add this to our incomplete data stash and read again.
            this.currentData.Add(lastChunk);
            return;
        }

        // This message contained at least 1 new line, so we split it and process per line.
        List<string> messages = lastChunk.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        foreach (string line in this.PruneReceivedMessages(messages))
        {
            this.OnDataReceived(line);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs through the messages collection and prepends data from a previous, incomplete, message
    /// and updates the internal message tracking state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="messages"></param>
    private List<string> PruneReceivedMessages(List<string> messages)
    {
        // Append the first line to the incomplete line given to us during the last pass if one exists.
        if (this.currentData.Any() && messages.Any())
        {
            messages[0] = string.Format("{0} {1}", string.Join(" ", this.currentData), messages[0]);
            this.currentData.Clear();
        }

        // If we have more than 1 line and the last line in the collection does not end with a line feed
        // then we add it to our current data so it may be completed during the next pass. 
        // We then remove it from the lines collection because it can be infered that the remainder will have
        // a new line due to being split on \n.
        if (messages.Count > 1 && !messages.Last().EndsWith("\r\n"))
        {
            this.currentData.Add(messages.Last());
            messages.Remove(messages.Last());
        }

        return messages;
    }

    private void OnDataReceived(string data)
    {
        var handler = this.DataReceived;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, data);
    }
}
```

#### Server

Now that we have the client async receiving and processing of data, we need to write the server component to actually accept incoming `Socket` connections asynchronously.

This class will have two events that the `Form` will subscribe to. One for when a client connects, and another for when the client disconnects. Each client that is connected, is assigned a `ConnectionState` and cached in a collection of `List<ConnectionState>`. This removes the need for you to keep a fragile counter of the number of clients connected.

You could optionally wire up a timer that periodically prunes the `List<ConnectionState>` collection. You can check if each instance in the collection has its `IsConnectionValid` set to true. If it returns false, remove it from the collection.

```
/// <summary>
/// The Default Desktop game Server
/// </summary>
public sealed class Server
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The user connection buffer size
    /// </summary>
    private const int UserConnectionBufferSize = 1024;

    /// <summary>
    /// The server socket
    /// </summary>
    private Socket serverSocket;

    /// <summary>
    /// The player connections
    /// </summary>
    private List<ConnectionState> connectedClients;

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for making access to the connectedClients collection thread-safe
    /// </summary>
    private object lockObject = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Server"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Server()
    {
        this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopped;
        this.connectedClients = new List<ConnectionState>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a client connects to the server.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> ClientConnected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a client is disconnected from the server.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> ClientDisconnected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the port that the server is running on.
    /// </summary>
    public int Port { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the maximum queued connections.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxQueuedConnections { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current server status.
    /// </summary>
    public ServerStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (this.Status != ServerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The server is either starting or already running. You must stop the server before starting it again.");
        }
        else if (this.Port == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can not start the server on Port 0.");
        }

        this.Status = ServerStatus.Starting;

        // Get our server address information
        IPHostEntry serverHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.Port);

        // Instance the server socket, bind it to a port.
        this.serverSocket = new Socket(serverEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.serverSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);
        this.serverSocket.Listen(this.MaxQueuedConnections);

        // Begin listening for connections.
        this.serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectClient), this.serverSocket);

        this.Status = ServerStatus.Running;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the server.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.DisconnectAll();

        // We test to ensure the server socket is still connected and active.
        this.serverSocket.Blocking = false;
        try
        {
            this.serverSocket.Send(new byte[1], 0, 0);

            // Message was received meaning it's still receiving, so we can safely shut it down.
            this.serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            // Error code 10035 indicates it works, but will block the socket.
            // This means it is still receiving and we can safely shut it down.
            // Otherwise, it's not receiving anything and we don't need to shut down.
            if (e.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10035))
            {
                this.serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopped;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects the specified IServerPlayer object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">The client to disconnect.</param>
    public void Disconnect(ConnectionState connection)
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.IsConnectionValid)
        {
            connection.CurrentSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            this.connectedClients.Remove(connection);
            this.OnClientDisconnected(connection);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects everyone from the server.
    /// </summary>
    public void DisconnectAll()
    {
        // Loop through each connection and disconnect them.
        foreach (ConnectionState state in this.connectedClients)
        {
            Socket connection = state.CurrentSocket;
            if (connection != null && connection.Connected)
            {
                connection.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                this.OnClientDisconnected(state);
            }
        }

        this.connectedClients.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a client connects.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnClientConnected(ConnectionState connection)
    {
        EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> handler = this.ClientConnected;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new ConnectedArgs(connection));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a client disconnects.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnClientDisconnected(ConnectionState connection)
    {
        EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> handler = this.ClientDisconnected;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new ConnectedArgs(connection));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the client to the server and then passes the connection responsibilities to the client object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The async result.</param>
    private void ConnectClient(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Connect and register for network related events.
        Socket connection = this.serverSocket.EndAccept(result);

        // Send our greeting
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Welcome to the Music App Server!");
        connection.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(asyncResult => connection.EndReceive(asyncResult)), null);

        // Fetch the next incoming connection.
        this.serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectClient), this.serverSocket);

        this.CompleteClientSetup(new ConnectionState(connection, UserConnectionBufferSize));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Caches the ConnectionState and has the state begin listening to client data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionState"></param>
    private void CompleteClientSetup(ConnectionState connectionState)
    {
        lock (this.lockObject)
        {
            this.connectedClients.Add(connectionState);
        }

        // Start receiving data from the client.
        connectionState.StartListeningForData();
        this.OnClientConnected(connectionState);
    }
}
```

#### Form

Now that we have our server code put together, the Form can be constructed. I just did a simple form, with a single button for connecting and a single multi-line textbox for viewing the data.

[image: Form Layout]

I added an event handler for the Form's `Loading` event and for the Button's `Clicked` event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Server server;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        server = new Server { Port = 9180, MaxQueuedConnections = 100 };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server.ClientConnected += OnClientConnected;
        server.ClientDisconnected += OnClientDisconnected;
    }

    private void OnClientDisconnected(object sender, ConnectedArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.textBox1.AppendText("A Client disconnected.\n")));
    }

    private void OnClientConnected(object sender, ConnectedArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText("New Client Connected.\n");
            e.ConnectedClient.DataReceived += OnClientSentDataToServer;
        }));
    }

    private void OnClientSentDataToServer(object sender, string e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.textBox1.AppendText($"{e}\n")));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.AppendText("Server starting.\n");
        server.Start();
        this.textBox1.AppendText("Server running.\n");
    }
}
```

This gives you a nice, clean, way to handle the server-side. Anytime you can avoid a while loop in your server, the better off you are. The actually code is a lot larger than what you posted, but will run much better on your server during runtime.