# Client's Socket.send aren't working well when another client joins

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I'm writing a chat program using sockets in C# Winform.
It works well with single client, but when I turn on another client, previous client's (worked well) Send function never works, but it keeps receiving data.

Here's my whole source code (because idk what's wrong with it, and I got some advices that I gave them poor details)

**Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace Player__Server_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket Serv;
        List<Socket> ClnSocket = new List<Socket>();
        List<string> MusList = new List<string>();
        List<string> Nickname = new List<string>();

        int ClnCounter = 0;
        int MusCounter = 0;
        int BufferingCount = 0;
        Socket socket;
        Thread run;
        private delegate void sDelegate(string sData, int socketIndex);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        new public string Left(string Text, int TextLength)
        {
            if (Text.Length < TextLength)
            {
                TextLength = Text.Length;
            }
            return Text.Substring(0, TextLength);
        }

        new public string Right(string Text, int TextLength)
        {
            if (Text.Length < TextLength)
            {
                TextLength = Text.Length;
            }
            return Text.Substring(Text.Length - TextLength, TextLength);
        }

        new public string Mid(string sString, int nStart, int nLength)
        {
            string sReturn;
            --nStart;

            if (nStart <= sString.Length)
            {
                if ((nStart + nLength) <= sString.Length)
                {
                    sReturn = sString.Substring(nStart, nLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    sReturn = sString.Substring(nStart);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sReturn = string.Empty;
            }
            return sReturn;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // prevent exception
            Stream fe = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Music.server", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            fe.Close();

            // Read "Music.server" file and add to MusList (List)
            string line;
            StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Music.server");
            while ((line = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                MusList.Add(line);
                MusCounter++;
            }
            fr.Close();

            // prevent exception
            Stream fa = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Account.server", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            fa.Close();

            Serv = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Serv.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9180));
            Serv.Listen(100);

            Thread accept = new Thread(this.Accept);
            accept.Start();
        }

        private void runChatting(object s)
        {
            byte[] str = new byte[2048];
            socket = s as Socket;
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        str = new byte[2048];
                        socket.Receive(str);
                        sDelegate sdelegate = new sDelegate(this.Receive);
                        this.Invoke(sdelegate, Encoding.Default.GetString(str), ClnSocket.IndexOf(socket));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ClnSocket.Remove(socket);
                            ClnCounter--;
                        }
                        catch { }
                        return;
                    }


                }
        }

        private string GetMusic(string MusName)
        {
            // Function :: return original information of music- search by name

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < MusCounter; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (MusList[i].IndexOf(MusName) > 0)
                    {
                        return MusList[i];
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void Receive(string sData, int socketIndex)
        {
            TextBox.AppendText("GET : " + sData);
            if (sData.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > 0) { ; } else TextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            sData = sData.Replace("\0", "");
            if (Left(sData,10) == "#musicadd#")
            {
                string TempData = Mid(sData, 11, sData.Length);
                string[] SpliteData = TempData.Split('#');
                if (GetMusic(SpliteData[1]) == null)
                {
                    Stream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Music.server", FileMode.Append);
                    StreamWriter ws = new StreamWriter(fs);
                    ws.WriteLine(SpliteData[0] + "#" + SpliteData[1] + "#" + SpliteData[2] + "#sc");
                    ws.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                    MusList.Add(SpliteData[0] + "#" + SpliteData[1] + "#" + SpliteData[2] + "#sc");
                    MusCounter++;
                }
                SendTo("#musicadd#" + SpliteData[1], socketIndex);
            }
            else if (Left(sData, 7) == "#login#")
            {
                SendAll(Mid(sData, 8, sData.Length) + " Connected." + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else if (Left(sData, 14) == "#requestmusic#")
            {
                string requestValue = GetMusic(Mid(sData, 15, sData.Length));
                SendAll("#buffermusic#" + requestValue);
                BufferingCount = 0;
            }
            else if (Left(sData, 12) == "#bufferdone#")
            {
                BufferingCount++;
                if (BufferingCount == ClnCounter)
                {
                    SendAll("#musicplay#");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SendAll(sData);
            }
        }

        private void SendAll(string sData)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < ClnSocket.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    ClnSocket[i].Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sData));
                }
                catch { }
            }
            TextBox.AppendText("POST : " + sData);
            if (sData.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > 0) { ; } else TextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void SendTo(string sData, int socketIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                ClnSocket[socketIndex].Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sData));
                TextBox.AppendText("POST TO (" + socketIndex.ToString() + ") : " + sData);
                if (sData.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > 0) { ; } else TextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        private void Accept()
        {
                while (true)
                {
                    ClnSocket.Add(Serv.Accept());
                    ClnCounter++;
                    run = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(this.runChatting));
                    run.Start(ClnSocket[ClnCounter - 1]);
                }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Serv.Close();
            this.Serv = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.ClnSocket.Count; i++)
            {
                this.ClnSocket[i].Close();
            }
            this.ClnSocket.Clear();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace MineSky_Player
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        public Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Thread run;
        string BufferingInformation;
        int current_min = 0, current_sec = 0;
        int duration_min = 0, duration_sec = 0;
        int MusCounter = 0;

        public string mynick { get; set; }
        string MyNick;

        List<string> MusList = new List<string>();

        public delegate void sDelegate(string sData);
        public Form1()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                socket.Connect("localhost", 9180);
                run = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Run));
                run.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // prevent exception
            Stream fe = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Music.client", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            fe.Close();

            // Read "Music.client" file and add to MusList (List)
            string line;
            StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Music.client");
            while ((line = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                MusList.Add(line);
                MusCounter++;
                MusicList.Items.Add(line);
            }
            fr.Close();

            MyNick = mynick;
        }

        new public string Left(string Text, int TextLength)
        {
            if (Text.Length < TextLength)
            {
                TextLength = Text.Length;
            }
            return Text.Substring(0, TextLength);
        }

        new public string Right(string Text, int TextLength)
        {
            if (Text.Length < TextLength)
            {
                TextLength = Text.Length;
            }
            return Text.Substring(Text.Length - TextLength, TextLength);
        }

        new public string Mid(string sString, int nStart, int nLength)
        {
            string sReturn;
            --nStart;

            if (nStart <= sString.Length)
            {
                if ((nStart + nLength) <= sString.Length)
                {
                    sReturn = sString.Substring(nStart, nLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    sReturn = sString.Substring(nStart);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sReturn = string.Empty;
            }
            return sReturn;
        }
        private void BufferTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Player.playState.ToString() == "wmppsPlaying")
            {
                Player.controls.stop();
                ToSocket("#bufferdone#");
                BufferTick.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player.controls.play();
        }

        private void Run(object s)
        {
            byte[] str = new byte[2048];
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    str = new byte[2048];
                    socket.Receive(str);
                    sDelegate sdelegate = new sDelegate(this.Receive);
                    IntPtr x;
                    if (!this.IsHandleCreated) x = this.Handle;
                    this.Invoke(sdelegate, Encoding.Default.GetString(str));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Lost." + Environment.NewLine + e.ToString());
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        public void Receive(string sData)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("GET : " + sData);
            sData = sData.Replace("\0", "");
            if (Left(sData, 10) == "#musicadd#")
            {
                if (MusicList.Items.Contains(Mid(sData, 11, sData.Length)))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Already in the list!", "MSPlayer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else
                {
                    Stream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Music.client", FileMode.Append);
                    StreamWriter ws = new StreamWriter(fs);
                    ws.WriteLine(Mid(sData, 11, sData.Length));
                    ws.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    MusList.Add(Mid(sData, 11, sData.Length));
                    MusicList.Items.Add(Mid(sData, 11, sData.Length));
                    MusCounter++;
                }
            }
            else if (Left(sData, 13) == "#buffermusic#")
            {
                PlayProgressBar.Value = 0;
                current_min = 0;
                current_sec = 0;
                Player.URL = "";
                BufferingInformation = Mid(sData, 14, sData.Length);
                playingLabel.Text = BufferingInformation.Split('#')[1];
                playLabel.Text = "Buffering...";
                Player.URL = "https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + BufferingInformation.Split('#')[0] + ";color=ff5500&show_comments=false&auto_play=true& color=a2eeff";
                BufferTick.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (Left(sData, 11) == "#musicplay#")
            {
                duration_min = Int32.Parse(BufferingInformation.Split('#')[2]) / 60;
                duration_sec = Int32.Parse(BufferingInformation.Split('#')[2]) % 60;
                playLabel.Text = "0:00 / " + duration_min.ToString() + ":" + duration_sec.ToString();
                PlayProgressBar.Maximum = Int32.Parse(BufferingInformation.Split('#')[2]);
                Player.controls.play();
                PlayTick.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Text_Board.AppendText(sData.Replace("\#\", "#"));
            }
        }

        public void Send(string sData)
        {
            sData = sData.Replace("#", "\#\");
            Send_Supplied(sData);
        }

        public void Send_Supplied(string sData)
        {
            if (Left(sData, 2) == "//")
            {
                sData = sData.ToLower();
                if (Left(sData, 6) == "//exit") Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                ToSocket(sData);
            }
        }

        private void ToSocket(string sData)
        {
            socket.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sData));
        }
        private void Text_Chat_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                string str = this.Text_Chat.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
                this.Text_Chat.Text = "";
                Send(MyNick + " : " + str + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            socket.Close();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void Button_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            socket.Close();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void MusicList_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToSocket("#requestmusic#" + MusicList.GetItemText(MusicList.SelectedItem));
        }

        private void Button_MusicAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddForm addform = new AddForm();
            addform.socket = socket;
            addform.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void MusicList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PlayTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Player.playState.ToString() == "wmppsPlaying")
            {
                current_sec++;
                PlayProgressBar.Value++;
                if (current_sec == 60)
                {
                    current_min++;
                    current_sec = 0;
                }

                playLabel.Text = current_min.ToString() + ":" + current_sec.ToString() + " / " + duration_min.ToString() + ":" + duration_sec.ToString();
                if (PlayProgressBar.Value == PlayProgressBar.Maximum)
                {
                    Player.controls.stop();
                    playingLabel.Text = "Not Playing";
                    playLabel.Text = "0:00 / 0:00";
                    PlayProgressBar.Value = 0;
                    PlayTick.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Addform and Enterform are not the problem, I think. I've tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get your code to compile when I copied it in to a new project, so I'm not sure. One thing is for sure though, you have to many `while` loops taking place here. I would recommend replacing those with the `async pattern` that the `Socket` class has available. It would remove all of the while loops. A little bit of extra abstraction would help as well.

I have broken the server up in to its own class, then provided each `Socket` connection a wrapper class that the server will hold a reference to.

Note that I am using Visual Studio 2015, so my string formatting is using the new C# 6.0 style. If you can not use C# 6, it is easy enough to convert back to `string.Format("{0}", foo);`

#### Server Status

We need to have a way of checking what the current server status is. This can be as simple as a small `enum`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides status values for the server to use, indicating its current state.
/// </summary>
public enum ServerStatus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The server has stopped.
    /// </summary>
    Stopped,

    /// <summary>
    /// Server is in the process of starting.
    /// </summary>
    Starting,

    /// <summary>
    /// Server is up and running.
    /// </summary>
    Running
}
```

#### ConnectedArgs

Next, the Server class needs to raise some events so that the `Form` code-behind can be told when a client connects, and when the client has sent the server a message. We will provide a class called `ConnectedArgs` as our event handler argument. This class will hold a reference to our actual client, using the wrapper class we will create next.

```
public class ConnectedArgs : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instances a new ConnectedArgs class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state">The state of a client connection.</param>
    public ConnectedArgs(ConnectionState state)
    {
        this.ConnectedClient = state;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the client currently connected.
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectionState ConnectedClient { get; private set; }
}
```

#### ConnectionState

This class is responsible for holding the `Socket` associated with the connected client, and handle receiving the clients message data asynchronously. This uses the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` async pattern [included with the Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx).

This class will have an event that will be used to notify the `Form` that a new message was received. Note that this was pulled from one of my existing projects, so the data parsing basically checks the buffer and if the buffer does not include a \r\n, it is considered incomplete. It caches it and waits for the next chunk of data from the client to process and try and complete. You will want to replace the `ProcessReceivedData` method with your custom method that handles processing the received data. When you are done, just push the results in to the `OnDataReceived` method so your `Form` can be given it.

```
public sealed class ConnectionState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The size of the buffer that will hold data sent from the client
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int bufferSize;

    /// <summary>
    /// A temporary collection of incomplete messages sent from the client. These must be put together and processed.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<string> currentData = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// What the last chunk of data sent from the client contained.
    /// </summary>
    private string lastChunk = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Instances a new PlayerConnectionState.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="player">An instance of a Player type that will be performing network communication</param>
    /// <param name="currentSocket">The Socket used to communicate with the client.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferSize">The storage size of the data buffer</param>
    public ConnectionState(Socket currentSocket, int bufferSize)
    {
        this.CurrentSocket = currentSocket;
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
        this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is raised when the server has received new, valid, data from the client.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<string> DataReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Socket for the player associated with this state.
    /// </summary>
    public Socket CurrentSocket { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the data currently in the network buffer
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets if the current network connection is in a valid state.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsConnectionValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CurrentSocket != null && this.CurrentSocket.Connected;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts listening for network communication sent from the client to the server
    /// </summary>
    public void StartListeningForData()
    {
        this.Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        this.CurrentSocket.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Receives the input data from the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The result.</param>
    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // If we are no longer in a valid state, dispose of the connection.
        if (!this.IsConnectionValid)
        {
            this.CurrentSocket?.Dispose();
            return;
        }

        int bytesRead = this.CurrentSocket.EndReceive(result);
        if (bytesRead == 0 || !this.Buffer.Any())
        {
            this.StartListeningForData();
            return;
        }

        ProcessReceivedData(bytesRead);
        this.StartListeningForData();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process the data we received from the client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytesRead"></param>
    private void ProcessReceivedData(int bytesRead)
    {
        // Encode our input string sent from the client
        this.lastChunk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        // If the previous chunk did not have a new line feed, then we add this message to the collection of currentData.
        // This lets us build a full message before processing it.
        if (!lastChunk.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            // Add this to our incomplete data stash and read again.
            this.currentData.Add(lastChunk);
            return;
        }

        // This message contained at least 1 new line, so we split it and process per line.
        List<string> messages = lastChunk.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        foreach (string line in this.PruneReceivedMessages(messages))
        {
            this.OnDataReceived(line);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs through the messages collection and prepends data from a previous, incomplete, message
    /// and updates the internal message tracking state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="messages"></param>
    private List<string> PruneReceivedMessages(List<string> messages)
    {
        // Append the first line to the incomplete line given to us during the last pass if one exists.
        if (this.currentData.Any() && messages.Any())
        {
            messages[0] = string.Format("{0} {1}", string.Join(" ", this.currentData), messages[0]);
            this.currentData.Clear();
        }

        // If we have more than 1 line and the last line in the collection does not end with a line feed
        // then we add it to our current data so it may be completed during the next pass. 
        // We then remove it from the lines collection because it can be infered that the remainder will have
        // a new line due to being split on \n.
        if (messages.Count > 1 && !messages.Last().EndsWith("\r\n"))
        {
            this.currentData.Add(messages.Last());
            messages.Remove(messages.Last());
        }

        return messages;
    }

    private void OnDataReceived(string data)
    {
        var handler = this.DataReceived;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, data);
    }
}
```

#### Server

Now that we have the client async receiving and processing of data, we need to write the server component to actually accept incoming `Socket` connections asynchronously.

This class will have two events that the `Form` will subscribe to. One for when a client connects, and another for when the client disconnects. Each client that is connected, is assigned a `ConnectionState` and cached in a collection of `List<ConnectionState>`. This removes the need for you to keep a fragile counter of the number of clients connected.

You could optionally wire up a timer that periodically prunes the `List<ConnectionState>` collection. You can check if each instance in the collection has its `IsConnectionValid` set to true. If it returns false, remove it from the collection.

```
/// <summary>
/// The Default Desktop game Server
/// </summary>
public sealed class Server
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The user connection buffer size
    /// </summary>
    private const int UserConnectionBufferSize = 1024;

    /// <summary>
    /// The server socket
    /// </summary>
    private Socket serverSocket;

    /// <summary>
    /// The player connections
    /// </summary>
    private List<ConnectionState> connectedClients;

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for making access to the connectedClients collection thread-safe
    /// </summary>
    private object lockObject = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Server"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Server()
    {
        this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopped;
        this.connectedClients = new List<ConnectionState>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a client connects to the server.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> ClientConnected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a client is disconnected from the server.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> ClientDisconnected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the port that the server is running on.
    /// </summary>
    public int Port { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the maximum queued connections.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxQueuedConnections { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current server status.
    /// </summary>
    public ServerStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (this.Status != ServerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The server is either starting or already running. You must stop the server before starting it again.");
        }
        else if (this.Port == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can not start the server on Port 0.");
        }

        this.Status = ServerStatus.Starting;

        // Get our server address information
        IPHostEntry serverHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.Port);

        // Instance the server socket, bind it to a port.
        this.serverSocket = new Socket(serverEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.serverSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);
        this.serverSocket.Listen(this.MaxQueuedConnections);

        // Begin listening for connections.
        this.serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectClient), this.serverSocket);

        this.Status = ServerStatus.Running;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the server.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.DisconnectAll();

        // We test to ensure the server socket is still connected and active.
        this.serverSocket.Blocking = false;
        try
        {
            this.serverSocket.Send(new byte[1], 0, 0);

            // Message was received meaning it's still receiving, so we can safely shut it down.
            this.serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            // Error code 10035 indicates it works, but will block the socket.
            // This means it is still receiving and we can safely shut it down.
            // Otherwise, it's not receiving anything and we don't need to shut down.
            if (e.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10035))
            {
                this.serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopped;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects the specified IServerPlayer object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">The client to disconnect.</param>
    public void Disconnect(ConnectionState connection)
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.IsConnectionValid)
        {
            connection.CurrentSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            this.connectedClients.Remove(connection);
            this.OnClientDisconnected(connection);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnects everyone from the server.
    /// </summary>
    public void DisconnectAll()
    {
        // Loop through each connection and disconnect them.
        foreach (ConnectionState state in this.connectedClients)
        {
            Socket connection = state.CurrentSocket;
            if (connection != null && connection.Connected)
            {
                connection.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                this.OnClientDisconnected(state);
            }
        }

        this.connectedClients.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a client connects.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnClientConnected(ConnectionState connection)
    {
        EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> handler = this.ClientConnected;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new ConnectedArgs(connection));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a client disconnects.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnClientDisconnected(ConnectionState connection)
    {
        EventHandler<ConnectedArgs> handler = this.ClientDisconnected;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, new ConnectedArgs(connection));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the client to the server and then passes the connection responsibilities to the client object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The async result.</param>
    private void ConnectClient(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Connect and register for network related events.
        Socket connection = this.serverSocket.EndAccept(result);

        // Send our greeting
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Welcome to the Music App Server!");
        connection.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(asyncResult => connection.EndReceive(asyncResult)), null);

        // Fetch the next incoming connection.
        this.serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectClient), this.serverSocket);

        this.CompleteClientSetup(new ConnectionState(connection, UserConnectionBufferSize));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Caches the ConnectionState and has the state begin listening to client data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionState"></param>
    private void CompleteClientSetup(ConnectionState connectionState)
    {
        lock (this.lockObject)
        {
            this.connectedClients.Add(connectionState);
        }

        // Start receiving data from the client.
        connectionState.StartListeningForData();
        this.OnClientConnected(connectionState);
    }
}
```

#### Form

Now that we have our server code put together, the Form can be constructed. I just did a simple form, with a single button for connecting and a single multi-line textbox for viewing the data.

[image: Form Layout]

I added an event handler for the Form's `Loading` event and for the Button's `Clicked` event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Server server;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        server = new Server { Port = 9180, MaxQueuedConnections = 100 };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server.ClientConnected += OnClientConnected;
        server.ClientDisconnected += OnClientDisconnected;
    }

    private void OnClientDisconnected(object sender, ConnectedArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.textBox1.AppendText("A Client disconnected.\n")));
    }

    private void OnClientConnected(object sender, ConnectedArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText("New Client Connected.\n");
            e.ConnectedClient.DataReceived += OnClientSentDataToServer;
        }));
    }

    private void OnClientSentDataToServer(object sender, string e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.textBox1.AppendText($"{e}\n")));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.AppendText("Server starting.\n");
        server.Start();
        this.textBox1.AppendText("Server running.\n");
    }
}
```

Due to the server running as a background process, you have to marshall the event handlers back to the UI thread when accessing the `TextBox`. You could abstract that piece out a bit as well, so that the `Server` and `ConnectionState` objects always push to the dispatcher you provide them. This reduces the number of `Invoke(Action)` invocations you have to do.

This works well with multiple connections. I started the server up, and then spun up two different connections across a couple different computers without any issues. You will need to customize the data processing and pushing messages to the client. This should at least solve your multiple connection issue, and be less stress on the CPU (no more while loops!).

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned, I wasn't able to get your code to compile, so I couldn't test your client code. I was able to connect to it however using telnet. Since my answer is abstracted out of the Form code-behind, you can just comment your stuff out and implement my solution, then test it. If you you still can't connect, I will provide a working client side example.

Comment: I applied it to my server code, and it works. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!